# Why is the static files giving 404 in the production server?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a Django server setup on development as well as the production server. The development server loads the static files but the production server gives 404 on loading (although it renders the URL).

I have already used the collectstatic method to accumulate my static files.

settings.py:

```py
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

urls.py (main_project)

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings  # new
from django.conf.urls.static import static  # new


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('stock_management.urls', namespace='stock_management')),
    path('auth/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

# if settings.DEBUG:  # new
# urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
#                       document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
# urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
#                       document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

urls.py (App: stock_management) :

```py
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import *
from django.conf import settings

app_name = 'stock_management'

urlpatterns = [
    # Stock:
    path('', stock_list, name='homepage'),
    path('stock/', stock_list, name='stock_list'),
    path('stock/add', stock_create_view, name='add_stock'),
    path('stock/<pk>/edit', stock_edit, name='stock_edit'),

    # Item:
    path('items/', item_list, name='item_list'),
    path('item/<pk>/edit', item_edit, name='item_edit'),
    path('item/<pk>/delete', item_delete, name='item_delete'),

    # API
    path('api/items', item_list_API, name='item_list_API'),

    # Gallery:
    path('items/gallery', item_gallery, name='item_gallery'),
]

# if settings.DEBUG:
#     # test mode
#     from django.conf.urls.static import static
#     urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
#                           document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
#     urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
#                           document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I want my static files to load in the server also.

Comment: What is your developing server ?

Comment: Untill now I haven't setup nginx yet... I am using the normal django development server in live also..

Comment: In the web server logs, what is the requested URL for the static files?  Is that the correct URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set DEBUG=False in settings.py Django stops serving static files. You need to configure a web server like Nginx for static files.

Here a helpful tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-local-django-app-to-a-vps